# Last slide in PowerPoint 2003 slideshow is always black

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

The last slide in my slideshow comes up as a black screen.

I've tried all of the recommendations in PowerPoint Help but it makes no difference which slide I put in the last position; it always comes up black. The presentation is fine in every view except the slide show.

What can I do to get the last slide to show up?

Comment: Are there little white words on top that say something like "end of slideshow, click to exit"?

Answer (score 3):

There's an option that may help.  In PowerPoint 2010, go to File, Options, Advanced, Slide Show, and clear the box next to "End with black slide".

Comment: Thank you, Hand-E-Food. I was able to find that option in 2003 version. It works now.

Comment: Glad to help!  Please remember to click the tick next to the answer that answered your question.  Frankly, I'm surprised this was the solution.  That option shouldn't remove the last slide from your presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind.

1. Custom Show is not showing the last slide
2. The last slide is hidden so it doesn't show up

[image]

Comment: While this screenshot is for PPT 2010, the same function exists in PPT 2003. Even still, hiding a slide keeps it from showing entirely - it won't even appear as black.

Answer (score 0):

nothing suggested worked for me until I hid the slide that wasn't showing and then unhid it!

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the same issue as the original question, or did you have another issue that resolved itself by hiding and unhiding the final slide? OP's issue was just a standard setting in PowerPoint which we pointed out how to disable.